# Use onComplete and page redirection of action function

Tags: actionfunction, redirect, action, oncomplete

I have a simple question.
Can I use action function to redirect to a new page using controller code and also at the same time use onComplete of the action function so that onComplete gets called before the page gets redirected using controller method.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: I do not think so as the action is not complete until the page it redirected thus the action function is no longer valid. Best way to know is give it a try.

Comment: already tried was not able to, but would like to know a work around

Comment: Well, you could add a parameter to the URL of the page you are calling and have a method in that pages controller do what you wanted the oncomplete in the previous actionfunction to do